# Xcode Swift how to place UIViewController beneath parent UIView Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller

I would like to make similar effect that Facebook app has. So I would like to create navigation slide-out effect.

But when I place `UIViewController` with menu beneath parent `UIViewController` with content and then I move parent view aside my menu doesnt show up. Everything I can see is black screen. But menu frame is in the right position.

Any sugestion what should I do?

Content view will be separate UIViewControllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in the same situation than you and finally I used a custom class which is inspired on FaceBook and Wunderlist apps and is really simple to add into the project:
https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

Answer (score 0):

The child view controller is always above parent view controller's view.
I think the old and the new view controllers should be siblings and use a parent view controller to add them both.
In fact, the child controllers of native UINavigationController are siblings rather than child-parent relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I would urge you not to do this on your own but to use one of the many libraries out there that have been heavily tested by many contributors. One of the good ones is [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) but there are many others. Take a look at [cococontrols](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/) for many more examples.

Answer (score 0):

I've previously implemented a similar mechanic to this using custom transitions, which were introduced in iOS7. For example: could present the menu modally, but using a custom transition have it appear from the left and only take up a proportion of the screen.

Using custom *interactive* transitions will also allow you to use a pan gesture recogniser to drag your main view controller back on top of your menu - like in the Facebook app.

Here's a good tutorial on Custom Transitions: http://www.thinkandbuild.it/ios7-custom-transitions/